# Constrain rectDraw inside UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

I have a UIView which inherits from a custom UIView subclass where the `drawRect` method looks like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, .85);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10.0, 10.0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 10.0);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}
```

I'm having it used in a UIView, where the views dimensions are: 320 Width and 10 Height. The problem is.. the width of the line I'm drawing is only .85, but I cannot decrease the height of the UIView below 10 without the line disappearing, how do I get the line to draw in the bounds of the UIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "width of the line" has nothing to do with the matter. Do you understand how Cartesian coordinates work? Look at what you're doing. You are drawing a line from `{10,10}` to `{310,10}`. So its y-coordinate is `10`. If the height of the view is less than 10, that will be below the bottom of the view and you won't see the line.

So if the height of the view is less than 10, make that `10` a smaller number. You can learn the height of the view by examining `rect` — that's what it's there for.

In general you should probably not be hard-coding these numbers at all; you should be calculating them in terms of the incoming `rect` values.